# SeleniumGrid Chrome options not work

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Has code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:6000/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

Has problem: if run local by

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver64", chrome_options=options)
```

all fine, but if use selenium grid - ChromeOptions not work. Open small visible window.

Can anyone know what the problem is?

HUB:

```
java -jar /path/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role hub -timeout 30 -browserTimeout 60 -port 6000
```

NODE:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/chromedriver64 -jar /path/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role webdriver -hub localhost:6000/grid/register -port 6002 -browser browserName=chrome
```

SELENIUM - 3.5
Python 3.5.2